Problem with threads in an MDI application: application waits when thread is executing
Over the past 15 years, I have been writing and maintaining an MDI application written in Delphi 7 that accesses a database. The program runs fine and I have no problems (normally) in adding or displaying data from the database.
A few days ago, I was tasked with creating a new form/report that calculates correlations from the data; this requires relatively dense code that does not allow usage of the UI whilst the correlation is being calculated. I thought that it would be better to have the correlation be calculated in a separate thread as I understand that this would 'free up' the UI. The thread sends a message to the main program when it has finished and this message causes the main program to open a new child window and display the correlation, so there is no use of 'synchronise'.
All of this works, BUT the application simply hangs and cannot be revived if I try to open any other form while the thread is executing. This obviates the whole point of using a thread! I have created a separate database connection within the thread, so this would seem not to be the problem.
The thread is invoked by the following code
DoCorrelThread (id1, id2, fdt, caption + ' ' + cbFromDate.text + ' Scale A = ' +
                            cbA.text + ', Scale B = ' + cbB.text, HandleTerminate);

HandleTerminate is a public procedure in the calling form; at the moment it prevents the calling form from being closed while the thread is executing - which is just dodging the real problem.
The thread code itself is as follows - this is an edited version that does not calculate correlations, but displays the problem.
unit correlthread;
interface

uses Windows, classes, DB, FMTBcd, SqlExpr, dbclient, messages, 
 sysutils, IBDatabase, IBCustomDataSet, IBQuery, Registry;

Procedure DoCorrelThread (ascale1, ascale2: longint; adt: tdatetime;
                      const atitle: string; proc: TMyProc);

implementation
type
 TCorrelThread = class (TThread)
 private
  scale1, scale2: longint;
  fdt: tdatetime;
  title: string;
  procedure Execute; override;
 public
  constructor Create (ascale1, ascale2: longint; adt: tdatetime;
                      const atitle: string; proc: TMyProc); reintroduce;
end;

constructor TCorrelThread.Create (ascale1, ascale2: longint; adt: tdatetime;
                              const atitle: string; proc: TMyProc);
begin
 inherited Create (true);
 FreeOnTerminate:= True;
 OnTerminate:= proc;
 scale1:= ascale1;
 scale2:= ascale2;
 fdt:= adt;
 title:= atitle;
 resume;
end;

procedure TCorrelThread.Execute;
var
 i, j, instance: integer;
 qTemp, qNewInstance: TIBQuery;
 ibdb: TIBDatabase;
 trans: TIBTransaction;

begin
 ibdb:= TIBDatabase.Create (nil);
 with TRegIniFile.create ('\software\nbn') do
  begin
   ibdb.databasename:= ReadString ('firebird', 'q4admin', '');
   free
  end;

 with ibdb do
  begin
   loginprompt:= false;
   params.add ('password=masterkey');
   params.add ('user_name=sysdba');
   sqldialect:= 1;
   connected:= true;
  end;

 trans:= TIBTransaction.create (nil);
 trans.defaultdatabase:= ibdb;
 qNewInstance:= TIBQuery.create (nil);
 qNewInstance.database:= ibdb;
 qNewInstance.Transaction:= trans;
 qNewInstance.sql.add ('select max (instance) from temp');

 qTemp:= TIBQuery.create (nil);
 qTemp.database:= ibdb;
 qTemp.transaction:= trans;
 qTemp.SQL.add ('insert into temp (instance, id, payload)');
 qTemp.sql.add ('values (:p1, :p2, :p3)');

 for i:= 1 to 100 do  // do something that takes some time
  begin
   qNewInstance.Open;
   instance:= qNewInstance.Fields[0].asinteger + 1;
   qNewInstance.Close;
   trans.active:= false;

   for j:= 1 to 100 do
    begin
     trans.StartTransaction;
     qTemp.Params[0].asinteger:= instance;
     qTemp.params[1].asinteger:= j;
     qTemp.params[2].asinteger:= i;
     qTemp.ExecSQL;
     trans.Commit;
     trans.active:= false;
    end;
  end;

 trans.free;
 ibdb.free;
 sendmessage (mainhandle, WM_ShowCorrel, instance, 0);
end;
Procedure DoCorrelThread (ascale1, ascale2: longint; adt: tdatetime;
                          const atitle: string; proc: TMyProc);
begin
 TCorrelThread.Create (ascale1, ascale2, adt, atitle, proc);
end;

end.

As I say, the code itself works fine, but the rest of the program cannot be accessed whilst the thread is executing. Where is the problem?

Is your code still compiled with Delphi 7? If so, you should add this tag to the question. If not, there are some better ways to handle new threads in more modern Delphis (don't know if these will fix the issue or not).

@HeartWare: I've added the Delphi 7 tag.

Please reduce your example by not using any DB stuff, but instead only doing a simple Delay( 300000 ) or such in the thread to see if your GUI still becomes unresponsive.

@AmigoJack: removing all the code and just having a simple 'sleep' command and sending the message to the main form worked - the rest of the program was responsive before the (empty) form popped up. I've moved all of what was previously defined in the datamodule to this unit, including the WM_Correl constant and the newInstance function - in fact, I removed the declaration of 'admindm' from the 'uses' clause to be sure - but the program behaves just the same. So it's something in the db code that is causing the problem.

I see you are using a datamodule, be aware that db connections cannot be used across threads, its better to create a separate db connection within the calc thread.

@whosrdaddy: my previous comment says that I removed the data module. I removed almost all of the db code and replaced it with code that defines the TIBDatabase, the transaction and a simple insert query that executes 1000 times. The problem still exists. Should I edit my original post and show the simplified code?

@No'amNewman yes, the simpler the example that still reproduces the problem, the better the chance of finding what the problem is.

@No'amNewman on a side note, your code lacks error handling. If an exception were ever thrown, you risk leaking a lot of resources.

@No'amNewman, sorry missed that fact, maybe interbase does something in the main thread that your thread is not doing, never used interbase but I guess the delphi units come with source code?

@whosrdaddy While Delphi 7 did include special version of Interbase Database Engine as 3dp party library but it did not include source code of the said library.

@SilverWarior: ah that sucks, I usually refuse to use components in Delphi without source code, makes life harder when you are chasing a bug :(.

@whosrdaddy Well the company Borland who is original author of Delphi in year 2000 decided to release Interbase under Open Source so it is possible that Delphi 7 already shipped with its source code.
